# Java app to check anagram using for loop and if statement

Tags: java

I'm working on another coding task for university. I am having trouble using a for loop (with another for loop and an if statement) to take a String parameter, and reorder it in alphabetical order. The task then requires us to check two phrases against each other to check if the phrases are anagrams. The loop is the bit I am stuck with. My for loop should output the first phrase in alphabetical order, but my if statement is not functioning as intended. The boolean statement is incorrect but I am unsure what I should be checking the phrase.charAt(i) against to record the letter.

We are not permitted to use an array to complete this task.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnagramApp {
    /**Method to reformat string in alphabetical order**/
    public static String orderString(String phrase){
        String output = "";
        for (char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <='z'; alphabet ++ ){
            for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++){
                if (phrase.charAt(i) == i){
                    output += phrase.charAt(i);
                }
            }

        }
        return (output);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        /**Setting scanner object to retrieve user input for both phrases **/
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first phrase");
        String phrase1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter second phrase");
        String phrase2 = sc.nextLine();

        /**Send phrases to lower case for parsing to new string in char order**/
        phrase1 = phrase1.toLowerCase();
        phrase2 = phrase2.toLowerCase();

        System.out.println(orderString(phrase1));
        System.out.println(orderString(phrase2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change condition in if statement to  `if (phrase.charAt(i) == alphabet)`

or you can use below function to check two string anagram

```
boolean checkAnagram(String st1, String st2)
{   int arr[]=new int[26];
    int l1=st1.length();
    int l2=st2.length();
    if(l1!=l2){
        return false;
    }
for(int i=0;i<l1;i++){
    arr[st1.charAt(i)-97]+=1;
    arr[st2.charAt(i)-97]-=1;
}
 for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
     if(arr[i]!=0) return false;
 }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are comparing with the index of the inner loop, `i`, you want to compare with the index of the outer loop, `alphabet`.

```
if (phrase.charAt(i) == alphabet)
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew I was doing something stupid with my if statement, but for the life of me couldn't see what I was doing wrong, thanks!